# How to change the default location of /home/.encryptfs

Tags: 12.04, encryption, raid, encfs

Situation:

1. I have a 2 large HDs setup in RAID 0 config and mounted in `/raid` (redundancy)
2. I moved my `/home` to `/raid/home`. I hacked around configs to ensure that Ubuntu understands that I want my `/home` to be `/raid/home`.
3. I've encrypted my `/raid/home/MYUSER`.
4. The `.encryptfs` directory decided to create itself in `/home/.encryptfs` which defeats the purpose of the whole operation. I lost redundancy *and* I have less disk space available.

Questions:

1. How can I safely move the `/home/.ecryptfs` to `/raid/home/.encryptfs`?
2. Is it possible to configure the machine to always create `.encryptfs` directories in specific places instead of defaulting to `/home/.ecryptfs`?

Comment: Please [edit] this question to change `loose` to `lose` or `lost` and remove `Thanks`.

Answer (score 2):

Question 1:

Move the folder `/home/.ecryptfs` to `/raid/home/.encryptfs`.

Create a link from `/home/.ecryptfs` to `/raid/home/.encryptfs` with the following command.

```
sudo ln --symbolic /raid/home/.encryptfs /home/.ecryptfs
```

Question 2:

I am not aware of any way to do as you ask.